# Email client destroys html

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email, smtp

I'm using Codeigniter to send emails, i created html in my view and used it as a message. used these settings for my configurations

```
$config = Array(
            'useragent' => 'GDS GIS',
            'protocol'  => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'localhost',
            'smtp_port' => 25,
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'priority'  => 1,
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap'  => TRUE,
            'wrapchars' => 70
        );
```

here is a sample of the first few lines of my html code in my view :

```
<body topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: 100%;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    color: #000000;" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" text="#000000">
```

but when i use it to send the email it breaks the html to this :

```
<body topmargin=3D"0" rightmargin=3D"0" bottommargin=3D"0" leftmargin=3D"0"=
 marginwidth=3D"0" marginheight=3D"0" width=3D"100%" style=3D"border-collap=
se: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height=
: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-te=
xt-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: 100%;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    color: #000000;" bgcolor=3D"#F0F0F0" text=3D"#000000">
```

in my testing environment i'm using [smtp4dev](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) and when i preview it in outlook it seems fine.

but when i install it on the client's server the returned html is like the broken one and everything is just wrong. i tried wrapping text to smaller numbers but no success.

one thing that seems to be working, if i break the lines myself this issue is solved but then i have to go through 1000 lines of html and break it to smaller chunks which is not the best practice.

i've tried to get some information from the headers of the email that the company sends, might be helpful .

```
Delivered-To: //EMAIL
Received: by 10.107.18.230 with SMTP id 99csp196343ios;
        Mon, 10 Oct 2016 19:30:00 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.194.106.169 with SMTP id gv9mr1454160wjb.129.1476153000519;
        Mon, 10 Oct 2016 19:30:00 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: //Sender Email
Received: from smtptc4.repsol.com (smtptc4.repsol.com. [195.53.125.138])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id bd4si1616304wjb.242.2016.10.10.19.29.59
        for //MY EMAIL
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Mon, 10 Oct 2016 19:30:00 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of //Sender Email designates 195.53.125.138 as permitted sender) client-ip=195.53.125.138;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of //Sender Email designates 195.53.125.138 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=//Sender Email
X-IronPort-AV: E=Sophos;i="5.31,327,1473112800";
    d="xls'32?scan'32,208,217,32";a="119964443"
Received: from unknown (HELO msge-2a-p1n1.tlm.com) ([172.26.224.31])
  by sltcapliron02b.repsolypf.com with ESMTP/TLS/AES128-SHA; 11 Oct 2016 04:29:51 +0200
Received: from MSGH-2A-P1N1.tlm.com (10.144.36.90) by msge-2a-p1n1.tlm.com (10.110.1.98) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.3.266.1; Mon, 10 Oct 2016 20:31:01 -0600
Received: from MSGX-MYCBJ-P1N2.tlm.com (10.105.100.6) by MSGH-2A-P1N1.tlm.com (10.144.36.90) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.3.266.1; Mon, 10 Oct 2016 20:29:49 -0600
Received: from MSGX-MYCBJ-P1N1.tlm.com ([fe80::b0b6:e222:e7bd:c274]) by MSGX-MYCBJ-P1N2.tlm.com ([::1]) with mapi id 14.03.0195.001; Tue, 11 Oct 2016 10:29:44 +0800
From: //Sender email
To: "Bardia Heshmati //MY EMAIL " //MY EMAIL
Subject: 
Thread-Topic: Vessel Backcharging.xls
Thread-Index: AdIjZ1J7nPayUpoXRAWDw15u+jpBYg==
Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2016 02:29:42 +0000
Message-ID: <364E4469C9AFCE4E8D3DDAB7CB8BE65884CA861D@MSGX-MYCBJ-P1N1.tlm.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
x-originating-ip: [10.123.30.8]
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="_005_364E4469C9AFCE4E8D3DDAB7CB8BE65884CA861DMSGXMYCBJP1N1tl_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Return-Path: //Sender Email
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: email message bodies can only be 80 chars long per line.

Comment: The "broken" HTML looks correct. If this looks broken in your client, it's your client which is broken, not the email.

Comment: Why would you to break the lines yourself? Assuming your using PHP to send the email just add line breaks every 80 chars.

Comment: True, that's what i suspected, but there is no way for me to fix the client's stone age smtp or imap/pop, they are using something internally on their intranet . i tried to get some info from their email headers but i'm not quite sure, maybe you can have a look

Comment: @ElefantPhace do you think if i change back the charwrap to 80 it might solve the issue ?

Comment: Yes I do, why would you not try it and find out? The headers don't matter, all clients will read 80 chars per line, and in this case they're adding an `=` sign which is breaking the HTML

Comment: @ElefantPhace i don't know i've added that 72 wrapchars because i knew it's going to be an issue, i've tried it without wrapchars.

what do you mean by add linebreaks every 80 chars ? you mean manually ?

Comment: @ElefantPhace it's not only linebreaks, if you see the sample i have `topmargin=3D"0"` what is that 3D thing

Comment: I don't know anything about codeigniter, so I don't know what that config param actually does. If I were you I'd take my long email  `$body` and every 80 chars add a `\n\r` that topmargin looks completely wrong though I don't know what that is

Comment: Looks like you also have syntax errors in your HTML message body...